# Dynamicly change padding when screen resize

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a structure where each section is in a `div` that has a `container` class on it. I also have sections between them that intentionally go beyond the screen view. I would like these sections to adapt to the `container` but only on the left side. I mean padding. I am using react and for style i use Tailwind. I am looking for solution that check container padding left and automaticly add i to div with section beyond screen.

This is ho my container class looks like:
`.container { @apply px-5 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-[1650px]; }`
and structure:

```
<div className="container">
section
</div>
<div>
section that goes beyond screen
</div>
```

Comment: Could utilize CSS media queries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could try using widths in `wh` this would resize with the screen.

Comment: i need to find way for padding left only becouse i have only 3 section like this. Is there any way to check padding left of container and applay it only on this three sections.